# Microsoft ODBC cannot create valid handle

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm using Microsoft's ODBC driver to connect a C++/Linux application to a SQL Server database running remotely, and when I try to connect to the database, the call fails with `SQL_INVALID_HANDLE`. Reading through their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/return-codes-odbc?view=sql-server-2017), I find this:

> SQL_INVALID_HANDLE    Function failed due to an invalid environment, connection, statement, or descriptor handle. This indicates a programming error. No additional information is available from SQLGetDiagRec or SQLGetDiagField. This code is returned only when the handle is a null pointer or is the wrong type, such as when a statement handle is passed for an argument that requires a connection handle.

Fair enough, but at no point in the creation of the handles and environment prior to the connect statement do I get any errors. Also, for the second argument, their documentation says I can pass in a null pointer if there is no desktop window (as is the case on this linux console application). Here is a MVCE, adapted from Microsoft's [example program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-2017):

```
#include "sql.h"
#include "sqlext.h"
#include "msodbcsql.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int, char**)
{
  using std::cerr;
  using std::endl;
  SQLHENV henv;  
  SQLHDBC hdbc;
  HWND dhandle = nullptr; // no desktop handle in linux
  SQLHSTMT hstmt;  
  SQLRETURN retcode;  
  SQLCHAR OutConnStr[255];  
  SQLSMALLINT OutConnStrLen;

  retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);  
  if (!(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    cerr << "SQLAllocHandle (environment) failed " << retcode << endl;

  retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
  if (!(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    cerr << "SQLSetEnvAttr failed " << retcode << endl;

  retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
  if (!(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    cerr << "SQLAllocHandle (connection) failed " << retcode << endl;

  retcode = SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);  
  if (!(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    cerr << "SQLSetConnectAttr failed " << retcode << endl;

  std::string dsn = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=*.*.*,1433;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***";
  retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, dhandle, (SQLCHAR*)dsn.c_str(), dsn.length(), OutConnStr, 255, &OutConnStrLen, SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT);
  if (!(retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    cerr << "SQLDriverConnect failed " << retcode << endl;

  // cleanup code redacted for brevity

  return 0;
}
```

The program outputs `SQLDriverConnect failed -2`, which is `SQL_INVALID_HANDLE`. I'm stumped. `hdbc` is clearly the right type, and examining it in the debugger shows me it is not null.

It may be worth noting that the exact same connection string works in a python program using `pyodbc`. It seems that the C++ program isn't even getting as far as looking at that string, though. It just doesn't like the handle I'm sending into the connect call.

Microsoft's documentation clearly says they provide no additional information. If anyone can provide any direction on how to diagnose/debug this, I'd appreciate it greatly.

This application uses gcc 4.9.1 on Centos 7.

Comment: I would try it without those attribute functions - they don't look right, and they are probably not necessary.

Comment: @NeilButterworth same result with them removed.

Comment: `if ((!retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))` - wrong bracketing.

Comment: Good catch. But I fixed it and it didn't change the result.

Comment: Please edit your question with corrected code

Comment: OK, now you need to get the diagnostic error messages  using  `SQLGetDiagRec` and associated functions. And maybe try `SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT`.

Comment: `(SQLCHAR*)dsn.c_str ()` Remove the cast.  What error does the compiler give you?  If you get the error, read it carefully.  Casting a string type is a sign that something is amiss, and you're silencing the compiler and closing your eyes to the error.

Comment: @Paul Actually, ODBC use requires lots of casting - there really is no alternative. And this cast is not wrong.

Comment: I added a call to `SQLGetDiagRec` right after the allocation of the environment handle, and it also failed with `SQL_INVALID_HANDLE`. So the problem is clearly there, happening very early. `SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT` made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

After two weeks of digging, this turned out to be some kind of versioning problem.

Eventually, this program will be doing some BCP uploads via Microsoft's extensions in `libmsodbcsql.so`. It turns out that library also has implementations of many of the `SQL*` functions, which are the ones that are failing in this test program. When I change the order of the link so that `libodbc.so` is before the MSFT extensions library so that the loader finds those implementations first, the program works fine.

I'm curious why this is, and it probably points to something else I'm doing wrong that may bite me down the road. But for now, at least, I am able to get connected to the database and do basic queries and updates.

Thanks to those who helped.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem !  I only spend 1 day debugging it, and not more thanks to this post; this was a though cookie; see my answer THANKS, StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

In Unix does the handle not have to be a non-null value for dialogs to be displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Dialogs are not part of this application/environment.

Comment: @John Sorry that didn't work. I meant that dhandle should be 1 or something instead of 0 when using SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT. I see that you have tried SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT so it cannot be that. The other thought I had was about the inconnectionstring, instead of giving a length  dsn.length() use SQL_NTS which denotes a null terminated string. If not that I would try adding 1 to the length of the string as the parameter.  I notice with python you use pyobdc will that work with C? Do you need to another ODBC-ODBC bridge to work in unix?

Answer (score 0):

For any handle in SQL Server, it has to be allocated before used!

So the order is Environment, Connection and Statement.

Example:

```
SQLHENV hEnv = nullptr;
SQLHDBC hDbc = nullptr;
SQLHSTMT hStmt = NULL;
```

Allocations

```
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt);
```

Below is sample code that may help you.

Basics fast,

Create table in your sql server database and insert some data

```
create table test (id int, name nvarchar(128));
```

Insert some data

```
insert into test (id,name) values (1, 'Awesome Name');
```

C++ Code to query items in the table

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SQLHENV hEnv = nullptr;
    SQLHDBC hDbc = nullptr;
    SQLHSTMT hStmt = NULL;

    /**
     * Allocate environment handle
     */
    SQLRETURN allocReturn = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);

    //Set environment
    SQLRETURN setEnvReturn = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

    //Allocate connection handle

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);
    SQLCHAR *connection_string = (SQLCHAR *)
            "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost,1433;DATABASE=database;UID=sa;PWD=password";

    //Connect to database
    SQLRETURN connReturn = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, connection_string, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL,
                                            SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    //Allocate Statement Handle
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt);

    //Create statement
    SQLCHAR *query = (SQLCHAR *) "SELECT * FROM TEST;";
    SQLRETURN sqlPrepareResponse = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS); //strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(query))

    //Bind columns
    SQLCHAR personName[20];
    SQLLEN personNameIndex;
    SQLRETURN bindNameResponse = SQLBindCol(hStmt, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, personName, sizeof(personName),
                                            &personNameIndex);


    SQLINTEGER personId;
    SQLLEN personIdIndex;
    SQLRETURN personIdBindResponse = SQLBindCol(hStmt, 1, SQL_INTEGER, &personId, 0, &personIdIndex);

    SQLRETURN execResponse = SQLExecute(hStmt);

    SQLRETURN fetchResponse;

    while ((fetchResponse = SQLFetch(hStmt)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {
        std::cout << "ID: [" << personId << "] :" << personName << std::endl;
    }


    /* Free the statement handle. */
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);

    /* Disconnect from the database. */
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);

    /* Free the connection handle. */
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);

    /* Free the environment handle. */
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error using similar code (that was working in Ubuntu 18.04, but not with a update to 20.04)

```
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

using this connection string

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=127.0.0.1, 1433;UID=SA;PWD=password;DATABASE=my_database;
```

this is my library link order

```
if(UNIX)
  find_program(LSB_RELEASE_EXEC lsb_release)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXEC} -is OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  message(STATUS "Building in " ${LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT})
  if("${LSB_RELEASE_ID_SHORT}" STREQUAL "Ubuntu")
    message(STATUS "Linking with SQL-Server library")
    set(lib_dep ${lib_dep} msodbcsql-17)
  endif()
  set(lib_dep ${lib_dep} pthread odbc dl)
endif()
```

As noted in the solution above, changing the link order fixed the problem

```
set(lib_dep ${lib_dep} pthread odbc dl msodbcsql-17)
```